# Jquery - Switch Case into Switch Case - Clear Switch Case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm creating a small app for my company which works by a range of switches. For example If some enters in Hi it will take them to the hi function and within that function is more switches. An example below:

```
var function = firstfunction {

     $('#INPUTBOX').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
             switch($('#INPUTBOX').val().toLowerCase()){

             case "contact":
             QuestionFunctionContact();
             break;

             case "additional":
             case "extra":
             case "next":
             MiscFunctionContact();
             break;
          };
        }
    });
};

var QuestionFunctionContact = function(){

  $('#INPUTBOX').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
             switch($('#INPUTBOX').val().toLowerCase()){

             case "address":
             $('#OUTPUT').val("Here's Our Address");
             break;

             case "email":
             case "email address":
             $('#OUTPUT').val("Here's Our Email");
             break;

             case "phone":
             case "number":
             $('#OUTPUT').val("Here's Our Phone");
             Anotherfunction();
             break;

             case "return":
             firstfunction();
             break;
          };
        }
    });
};
```

This is just a small example with some of the ids changed.

My issue is I will need to clear the switches after being used until called again as the issue is once the function has ran it is usable even after leaving the switch (the cases ect) and most importantly the default case will also pass over figures. 
I need the default to store custom variables with each switch which is why I don't want them to pass on between the switches.

Edit -

The cases on the switches will either append to a div or take you to another function. There is around 15 - 20 functions connected to each other using switches some of the parents have a few children.

When you enter a value into the INPUTBOX and press enter then it will take you to one of the cases, within the cases you will either be taken to another function which will have a switch case or get a output to the OUTPUT class (The output being a box which is being append too for back tracking)

My next goal is to have a "sorry try one of these" but it only works on the current switch. If I was to give each switch a default it carries onto the next so it would list "Sorry try one of these" for all previous cases.

Hope this explains it a bit better

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with this code so that the community can understand on what you are trying ?

Comment: The App is at 2400 lines of code, I will make a small version

Comment: In Short - https://jsfiddle.net/qdu39xtp/3/ The default sticks meaning NO LUCK 1 and NO LUCK 2 will be appended to the div even on a new switch

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://jsfiddle.net/qdu39xtp/4/

Comment: Yeah, I got it working within my code but if you go to "contact" then enter anything non related you will get NO LUCK 1NO LUCK 2. I need to to say either NO LUCK 1 or NO LUCK 2 depending on which of the cases you are on (there are more than 2 on the live code)

Answer (score 0):

I added a refactored and fixed example of what i think your trying to do. Please see the comments in the snippet.

```js
/**
 * var function = firstfunction { will not work.
 * And, you need to call this function somewhere. I did so in the bottom.
 * Also this function must probably pass a value to your QuestionFunctionContact function.
 * I did this by providing the value to the function in the contact switch.
 */
var firstfunction = function() {

     $('#INPUTBOX').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
     
     var value = $('#INPUTBOX').val().toLowerCase(); // my general practice: use a value >=twice? store it to a variable
     
             switch(value){

             case "contact":
             QuestionFunctionContact(value);
             break;

             case "additional":
             case "extra":
             case "next":
             //MiscFunctionContact(); // dont know what this does...
             break;
          };
        }
    });
    
};
/**
 * This one was waiting for keypress again. 
 * Does not make sense since its called by the firstfunction that already used all keyup events.
 * Make it receive a value instead of acting on events.
 */
var QuestionFunctionContact = function(inputValue){
    
    var outputElem = $('#OUTPUT');

             switch(inputValue){

             case "contact": 
             case "address":
             outputElem.html("Here's Our Address");
             break;

             case "email":
             case "email address":
             outputElem.html("Here's Our Email");
             break;

             case "phone":
             case "number":
             outputElem.html("Here's Our Phone");
             //Anotherfunction(); // dont know what this does...
             break;
             
          };
};
firstfunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="INPUTBOX">
<em>Type "contact" for example</em>
<div id="OUTPUT"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, MiscFunctionContact(); takes you to another function, I was trying to shorten it. I will edit the post to explain it a bit better